# Beginning C Program

Tags: c, cs50

I was working though some beginning problem sets with Harvard's online CS50 class. I got the problem to work correctly but I was wondering if there would possibly be a cleaner or better way to get the program to work.

The goal of the program is to print a right-aligned pyramid comprised of hash-tags and space characters. Any guidance in regards to style or tricks would be very welcome.

```
/* Creating the mario program, whose goal is to create a 
*  pyramid by accepting input from the user to get the 
*  height then aligning the pyrimid to the right.
*
*/

#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>

int main(void)
{

    // get user input and set to variable
    printf("Height: ");
    int height = GetInt();

    int i, j, k;
    for(i = 1 ; i < height; i++)
    {

        // create n-1 spaces
        for(k = (height - 2); k > (i-1); k--)
        {
            printf("%c", ' ');      
        }

        // create n+1 hash tags
        for(j = 0; j < (i+1); j++)
        {
            printf("#");
        }

        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Ask yourself what you mean by cleaner/better? What makes this program dirty/bad in your opinion.

Comment: In addition to the comment from @PreetSangha , my advice would be not to get too obsessed with cleanliness/efficiency in your code when you're just starting out. Your desire for neat code will automatically develop as you write more complex programs, but programming is ultimately about writing working, useful programs. Optimisation and efficiency are things we require as our programs get more complex and resource intense

Comment: @leemo Optimization and efficiency are, but readability and basic good practices aren't.

Comment: By the way, this code looks just fine to me. Apart from the superfluous parentheses. (And I rarely say that.)

Comment: @H2CO3 - Agreed, but my comment about not getting to obsessed with this before fully understanding the concepts still stands.

Comment: @PreetSangha I agree with you completely, the code prints the pyramid and therefore is acceptable. I am just trying to make sure that my syntax and style is sound.

Comment: @leemo good advice, I think the more I write the easier this will get. Appreciate the feedback!

Comment: A welcome change from "this is my code so far `main() { /* to do */ }`". Your code looks fine: it's readable, consistent in style of spacing and bracketing, and It Does The Job. Don't worry, stylish *code* comes later.

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming by cleaner you mean "spiffy and fancyer".

This looks spiffy to me:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>

int main(void) {
    // get user input and set to variable
    printf("Height: ");
    int height = GetInt();
    int hm2 = height - 2;

    int j, k;
    for(int i = 1 ; i < height; i++) {
        // create n-1 spaces
        for(k = hm2; k > (i-1); k--)
            printf("%c", ' ');      

        // create n+1 hash tags
        for(j = 0; j < (i+1); j++)
            printf("#");

        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

---

However, don't get too caught up in making your code fancy. Although it's nice if you're working with others, or yourself really. Your example looked fine.

Now, **optimization**-wise, that's something to worry about. Just remember that too much optimization can potentially break your program.

Comment: But this will not print the *cleaner and better* [pyramid](http://ideone.com/pmoYvY) :)

Comment: Not THAT important, but I think the removal of the curly brackets in both inner loops is error prone.

Comment: I think i like creating the variable outside of the for loop a bit more, maybe cleans up the readability a bit. But i think i understand the argument that there are many ways to skin this cat.

Answer (score 2):

For everyone's consideration: this is what "all style and no readability" looks like :)

```
i = 0;
while (i++ < height*height)
    printf ("%c%s", (i-1)/height < height-(i-1)%height-1 ? ' ' : '#',
    i % height ? "" : "\n");
```

It is nigh on impossible to see what the code does without running it. If there is to be a follow-up exercise, this is hard to re-write to form, say, an even-sided pyramid. I'd probably throw this away and start again with the basics, before concatenating it again into a little monster such as this.

---

(later) Ever so slightly more neat to put the `i++` at the end, so two times `(i-1)` gets traded for a slightly more complicated end-of-line test:

```
i = 0;
do
    printf ("%c%s", i/height < height-i%height-1 ? ' ' : '#',
    i % height==height-1 ? "\n" : "");
while (++i < height*height);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think by cleaner and better way you mean to be a perfect shaped right angled triangle pyramid.
For this you should do as
Change

```
printf("Height: ");
```

to

```
printf("Height: \n\n");
```

and

```
for(i = 1 ; i < height; i++)
```

to

```
for(i = 0 ; i < height; i++)
```

And see the [sample output](http://ideone.com/eM3Lek).

Comment: Ah yes! I think you are right. it was bothering me that i had to have both "(height -2)" and "(i-1)" for the creation of the spaces. Seemed a bit superfluous

Answer (score 0):

Here's a suggestion:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>

int main(void) {
    //initialize variables
    int height, hm2, j, k, i;

    printf("Height: \n");
    // Get user input
    height = GetInt();
    hm2 = height - 1;
    for(i = 0; i < height; i++) {
        // create n spaces
        for(k = hm2; k > i; k--)
            printf("%c", ' ');      

        // create n+1 hash tags
        for(j = 0; j < i+1; j++)
            printf("#");

        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Result if the user entered a 5 for the height:

```
Height: 
    #
   ##
  ###
 ####
#####
```

A couple things I considered with this version of the code:

-In C, it's good practice to declare all variables separately from giving them a value and assign values later.  Some compilers may bring up this error if you to declare and assign a value in a for loop: "error: ‘for’ loop initial declarations are only allowed in C99 mode".  These changes are considered with what I have provided.

```
//initialize variables                                                            
int height, hm2, j, k, i;
```

-I added a newline here

```
printf("Height: \n");
```

-Instead of hm2 = height - 2 I changed it to:

```
hm2 = height - 1;
```

-First loop, now we give i a value and set it to 0 to meet the other changes that were made:

```
for(i = 0; i < height; i++) {
```

-For the loop creating n spaces I changed it to:

```
for(k = hm2; k > i; k--)
```

-Finally removed parenthesis (no need in this case) in last for loop:

```
for(j = 0; j < i+1; j++)
```

Cheers