# CS50 Mario Pyramid in C - Hashes not printing out as expected by code logic

Tags: cs50

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>

int main(void)
{
    int height, row, spaces, hashes; //declare all variables to be used    
    do //prompt the user for valid height inputs that are non-negative and less than 23.
    {
        printf("Height:");
        height = get_int();
    } while ((height < 0) || (height > 23));

    for (row = 1; row <= height; row ++) // iterate through each row of the height
    {
       for (spaces = (height - row); spaces >= 0; spaces--) //print the number of spaces for the ith row
       {
           printf(" ");
       }
       for (hashes = (row + 1); hashes <= (height + 1); hashes++) //print the number of hashes for each row
       {
           printf("#");
       }
       printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Not sure what I am missing in the above code. The spaces print as expected, but the behavior of the hashes is inverted, printing the highest and decreasing.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating a "Mario Style Pyramid"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38961481/creating-a-mario-style-pyramid)

Comment: I hope that you'll get it after reading [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38961720/6290553).

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume the user submitted `12` as height.
You start the outer loop with `row = 1`, which gives spaces from `height - row = 11` to `0`, makes 12 spaces.
The hashes go from `row + 1 = 2` to `height + 1 = 13`, makes 12 hashes.
Next iteration of the loop: 11 spaces, 11 hashes.

What you have expected can be achieved if you changes the second inner loop:

```
for (hashes = 0; hashes < row; hashes++) //print the number of hashes for each row
```

If this is not exactly what you need, change beginning of the loop to `hashes = 1;` or the end to `row - 1;` or whatever you need.

Your mistake was to assume that `hashes++` makes it ascending. It does, technically, but it only changes the order of the loop, not how often it is run. Since you do not need the actual value of `hashes`, the order is irrelevant. The only thing that counts is how often the loop is run ;)